# combining vector and list columns within a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to determine how I can add a column which is a vector to a column which is a list within the same data frame

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  dens = rnorm(1000),
  id = sample(1:10, 1000, replace = TRUE),
  size = sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  group_by(id, size) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  mutate(
    dens_est = map(data, ~ KernSmooth::bkde(.$dens) %>% 
                 bind_rows)
  )
```

Using the results from the above, I would like to add a column to the `dens_est` data frames with the associated value of the `size` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` to loop through the `dens_est` and `size` column and use `mutate` to create the `size` column for each data frame.

```
set.seed(1234)

library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(
  dens = rnorm(1000),
  id = sample(1:10, 1000, replace = TRUE),
  size = sample(1:3, 1000, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  group_by(id, size) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  mutate(
    dens_est = map(data, ~ KernSmooth::bkde(.$dens) %>% 
                     bind_rows)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    dens_est = map2(dens_est, size, ~.x %>% mutate(Size = .y))
  )

df$dens_est[[1]]
# # A tibble: 401 x 3
#       x          y  Size
#   <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
# 1 -4.38 0.00000568     3
# 2 -4.35 0.0000118      3
# 3 -4.33 0.0000159      3
# 4 -4.30 0.0000185      3
# 5 -4.27 0.0000213      3
# 6 -4.25 0.0000246      3
# 7 -4.22 0.0000284      3
# 8 -4.20 0.0000327      3
# 9 -4.17 0.0000376      3
# 10 -4.14 0.0000432     3
# # ... with 391 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Use mutate and map2:

```
df %>%
  mutate(data = map2(data, size, 
         function(x, y) mutate(x, size = y)))
```